# jQuery - send POST data and return result

Tags: jquery, html, post

Guys i'm working on simple jQuery script which is posting data and return result.

Here is my Code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.post( "./Sender.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
   $( "#result" ).html( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Sender.php:

```
<?PHP
$name = $_POST["name"];
echo $Name;
?>
```

But it is returning blank result, why ?

How can i send post data on page load and then return any result back?

Thank you!

Comment: Just `echo $name;` ?

Comment: This question demonstrates that you aren't watching your error logs. Figure out how to do that ASAP, it will save you tons of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, names of variables are case-sensitive.

Just try to echo `$name` instead of `$Name`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php